# Reading Client machine Registry from WEB Page

Tags: javascript

To Support our WEB Page, We will give some setup(exe) to be installed in client machine. While installing Our SETUP, we will set/Create some registry key and values. Whenever Our Web page loads on that machine, we have to verify whether particular setup installed or not. How can i do with Vb/C#

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can use an antiquated version of IE and its `ActiveXObject`, you can't read the registry from client-side web page code in a browser. Imagine the security concerns if you could.

Comment: ActiveXObject will only work in IE. right? I need across all browser. Even finding whether particular exe installed or not is better for me

Comment: @RajaSekaran - Right. As I said, "unless you can use an antiquated version of IE **and** its `ActiveXObject`...".